# IdentityServer4 webapi returning 401 unauthorized with self signed cert

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I'm new to .NET Core and IdentityServer4. I started building an app on localhost using IISExpress together with Temporary Signing Credentials. Everything works great, I'm able to get access token via resource owner password, and make calls to authorized API methods.

However, when I deploy to a server (staging env), I'm always getting a 401 unauthorized for api calls that require authorization. 
Before deployment, I made changes (as described below) on my localhost and tested it, result is as expected as before.

1. Change Temporary Signing Credentials to

   ```
   services.AddIdentityServer()
               .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Certs\DemoAuth.pfx"))
   ```
2. Create a self signed cert according to steps posted by David Smit

   ```
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\makecert" -n "CN=IdentityServer4Auth" -a sha256 -sv IdentityServer4Auth.pvk -r IdentityServer4Auth.cer -b 01/01/2017 -e 01/01/2025

   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\pvk2pfx" -pvk IdentityServer4Auth.pvk -spc IdentityServer4Auth.cer -pfx IdentityServer4Auth.pfx
   ```
3. Set app pool settings to true for load user profile

Prior to setting load use profile to true, I've also tried with the following code:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Certs\DemoAuth.pfx", "pwd-here", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet))
```

Can someone point me towards the right direction on the issue I'm facing when deployed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you deploying to? Azure? Can you add the logs? Are there any errors? My `cert.pfx` is in the same folder as my `Startup.cs` so you could try this and just use the filename without the path

Comment: @moritzg If the .pfx path is wrong, I'll be receiving an error on it and will not be able to get the access token as well. But nonetheless, let me give it a shot.
It's not on cloud, just a dedicated server within the company's network.
Thank you

Comment: @moritzg Just tried your suggestion with the same outcome. Any other possibilities?

Comment: Hmm okay, can you turn on logging and edit your question to include the output? I guess your server does not trust the certificate. Set up SSL so you can reach your server via `https://` and try it again.

Comment: @moritzg Thanks. I'll try that out and update as soon as I can.

Comment: @moritzg I found out from the logs I made a silly mistake in the configurations. The IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions's Authority was specified with my localhost. Hence it was working on my localhost, but not the server. Sorry and thanks so much for your time. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the certificate is in the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities (i.e. import your cert into that location in Windows Certificate Manager).

Make sure the account running the AppPool has permission to that certificate (right click the cert and use "Manage Private Keys" menu option under "All Tasks").